# regex for various date formats

Tags: regex, validation, date

I am newer to Regex and I am wondering if someone can help.  I am not even sure if Regex is the best option for what I am trying to do.

I have a array of string that I am looking through.  I want to find all items in the array that match various date formats.  Here are the example formats that I am trying to match on.

Apr 1, 2012 - Short Month Name with No Leading Zero on Day - Match

Apr 01, 2012 - Short Month Name with Leading Zero on Day - Match

April 1, 2012 - Full Text Month Name with No Leading Zero on Day - Match

April 01, 2012 - Full Text Month Name with Leading Zero on Day - Match

4/1/2012 - No Leading Zeros on Month and Day - Match

04/01/2012 - Leading Zeros on Month and Day - Match

02/29/2012 - If Year is a Leap, allow 2/29 - Match

13/12/2001 - Month outside 1-12 - No Match

02/30/2012 - Too Many Days in a Month - No Match

02/29/2011 - If Not a Leap Year - No Match

Current Regex that I have developed.

```
\b(?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y) |Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))|(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.,](0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])
```

I can develop regex to detech the various parts of each of these formats, but linking them together is so that I would only get one match.  Currently it matches twice (Month, Month + Day).  I only want it to match when the entire match is meet.

Thanks

jlimited

Comment: try [`DateJS`](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: Using ``RegEx`` you might match some date strings, but you could never make a ``pure regex pattern`` to validate a date field. You may win a few battle not an war! Suppose the ``leap year issue``.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it all in one simple regex? That sounds more complicated that it should be. Besides, think of adding new formats in the future, for example? It would not be straightforward. I would rather group similar patterns into a single regular expression, e.g. "Apr 1, 2012", "April 01, 2012" in one group, and then "04/01/2012", "02/30/2012". Anyway, I guess at some point, you will need to process the different components of the date into a common representation. And for that, you will likely need dedicated code.

It is not perhaps the answer you want, but as a general principle, always try to break a large problem into smaller problems you can easily solve.

Cheers,

Jose